# How can I get the unit name of a class if I have the class / VMT address only

Tags: delphi

As I read [here](http://hallvards.blogspot.de/2006/03/hack-8-explicit-vmt-calls.html),

> the VMT also contains a number of “magic” fields to support features
>   such as parent class link, instance size, class name, dynamic method
>   table, published methods table, published fields table, RTTI table,
>   initialization table for magic fields, the deprecated OLE Automation
>   dispatch table and implemented interfaces table

It looks like the VMT does not include a field which contains the unit name where the class is defined. Is there some 'compiler magic' involved?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I cannot see why the VMT should be involved here. TObject already exposes a `class function UnitName` for that.

[System.TObject.UnitName](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.TObject.UnitName)

Comment: For versions earlier than D2009, one can use `typinfo.GetTypeData(TSomeClass.ClassInfo).UnitName`

Answer (score 1):

VMT includes a pointer to class RTTI (provided by `ClassInfo` method); class RTTI includes a class unit name. As an exercise you can get unit name from VMT pointer, I have written this (tested on Delphi XE):

```
uses TypInfo;

type
  TObj = class

  end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Obj: TObj;    //  dummy obj instance
  VMT: Pointer;
  P: Pointer;   // class info

begin
// you can get VMT pointer so
  Obj:= TObj.Create;
  VMT:= PPointer(Obj)^;
  Obj.Free;
// or so
  VMT:= Pointer(TObj);

  P:= PPointer(PByte(VMT) + vmtTypeInfo)^;
  if P <> nil then
    ShowMessage(GetTypeData(P).UnitName);
end;
```

Comment: Since, as you mention, the RTTI pointer is available from the `ClassInfo` method, why do you demonstrate such a circuitous route to get the very same information? You could replace all that code with simply `P := TObj.ClassInfo`.

Comment: @RobKennedy - You can't call `ClassInfo` method directly having only a pointer to VMT of unknown class. You may try to typecast VMT pointer somehow, but I have not found how to do it.

Comment: @Serg Just cast the vmt pointer to `TClass`. Then you can make a one-liner: `TypInfo.GetTypeData(TClass(vmt).ClassInfo).UnitName`

Comment: But how and why are you getting a raw pointer to a VMT in the first place? Just use the class reference or object reference directly. You don't even need any knowledge of the concept of "VMT" at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure MessageException(E: Exception);
var
  TI: TypInfo.PTypeInfo;
begin
  TI := E.ClassInfo;
  if Assigned(TI) then
  begin
    Dialogs.MessageDlg(TypInfo.GetTypeData(TI).UnitName + '.' +
      E.ClassName + ': ' + E.Message, Dialogs.mtError, [Dialogs.mbOK], 0, Dialogs.mbOK);
  end
  else
  begin
    Dialogs.MessageDlg(E.ClassName + ': ' + E.Message, Dialogs.mtError, [Dialogs.mbOK], 0, Dialogs.mbOK);
  end;
end;
```

Note that ClassInfo must be tested for **nil**. E.g. SysUtils.ERangeError does not have it.